# What is a series expansion for $\zeta(s)$ valid iff $\operatorname{Re}(s)>\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-zeta, rational-numbers, analyticity

Let $s$ be complex and $\zeta(s)$ the Riemann Zeta function. What is a series expansion for $\zeta(s)$ valid iff $\operatorname{Re}(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ ?

I want a series expansion such that $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n}^{\infty} f(n,s)$ where the $f(n,s)$ are standard functions without irrational constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really an answer but perhaps close.

A simple solution without the conditions that $f(n,s)$ are standard functions though is relatively easily obtained by :

$$\zeta^*(s)=\frac 1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

$$\zeta^{**}(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^{s+\frac{1}{2}}}$$

$\zeta(s)=\dfrac{\zeta^*(s)\zeta^{**}(s)}{\zeta^{*}(s+\dfrac{1}{2})}$

and then simplifying $\zeta^*(s)\zeta^{**}(s)$ to a single sum by using a sum over the divisors.

However I would dare to call this a "nonelegant" solution.

Also I think there is another solution but not independant of RH. (using series for the multiplicative inverse of $\zeta(s)$ with conjectured  domains of convergeance or such )

Bye uniqueness of analytic continuation ( but not of series representations of them ! ) I doubt that a answer to the OP is possible since that would seem like an oversimplification of deep number theoretical stuff like sum over divisors in unexpected ways...

Im speculating here so this finishes my partial answer/comments.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

For  Re$(s)>0\,\;,\;\;s\neq 1$ :

$$\zeta(s)=\frac 1{1-2^{1-s}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}$$

You must check (1) that the infintie series there converges in the wanted domain and (2) the poles of the factor multiplying the series ad in fact removable (or "fake poles", if you will)

Comment: Im sorry But I asked "iff" not "if". So its not an answer. And I do not see how its a hint.

Comment: Do you see *any* difference in this case between if and iff? Do you know about uniqueness of analytic continuation? And the above is a hint since you must (perhaps) work mathematically your way until you reach the above, of course.

Comment: I do not know about uniqueness. Plz explain. thanks.

Comment: I can't: it's way too involved and long to do it here. Read any complex analysis book or google it. Anyway, as analytic cont. is unique when possible the above gives *the* anal. continuation of $\,\zeta(s)\,$ to Re$\,(s)>0\;,\;s\neq 1\;$ , thugh you can *also* get an integral form (not a very nice-looking one imo.)

Comment: Yes. And I know how to prove uniqueness of analytic continuation. But I asked for $Re(s)>0.5$. So the domain of converge of the hint is too large.

Comment: Well, you already have for Re$\,(z)>0\;$ and, by uniqueness of analytic cont., this *has to be* the same as for Re$\,(z)>0.5\;$ ...:)

Comment: With respect but its not funny. Its not an IFF condition for $Re(s)>0.5$ even though it is numerically the same at those places.

Comment: Ok @Mick, perhaps you're looking for some other form which, for Re$\,(z)>0.5\;$, will **have** to be equivalent with the given one.